# how to list x-axis as countries instead of numbers in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, bar-chart

I was trying to create a bar graph in jupyter notebook with country in the x-axis and impressions in the y-axis. Not sure why the countries are being converted into the index numbers for each country instead. Also not sure why it creates 2 charts, with one of them being empty. Any idea on how I can fix this?

```
impunder1000 = dataset2.loc[totimps < 1000, ['Total impressions']]
countryunder1000 =dataset2.loc[totimps < 1000, ['Country']]

imp1000 = dataset2.loc[(totimps > 1000) & (totimps < 10000), ['Total impressions']]
country1000 = dataset2.loc[(totimps > 1000) & (totimps < 10000), ['Country']]

imp10000 = dataset2.loc[(totimps > 10000) & (totimps < 100000), ['Total impressions']]
country10000 = dataset2.loc[(totimps > 10000) & (totimps < 100000), ['Country']]

imp100000 = dataset2.loc[(totimps > 100000) & (totimps < 1000000), ['Total impressions']]
country100000 = dataset2.loc[(totimps > 100000) & (totimps < 1000000), ['Country']]

imp1000000 = dataset2.loc[(totimps > 1000000) & (totimps < 10000000), ['Total impressions']]
country1000000 = dataset2.loc[(totimps > 1000000) & (totimps < 10000000), ['Country']]


x = countryunder1000
y = impunder1000

plt.xlabel('Country')
plt.ylabel('Impressions')



plt.title('Countries With Imps Under 1000')

ax = plt.axes()

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (30,5)
plt.figure
my_plot = x, y.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Thanks!

[image: screenshot]
[image]

Comment: Can you please include the code in the question?

Comment: that is the code. the stuff i wrote above was just reading the csv file

Comment: Code in the image is barely readable. It would help if you provide a code whose results can be reproduced.

Comment: Ohhhh okay sorry about that. Just uploaded another screenshot. Is that more helpful? I appreciate it thanks!

Comment: No. Screenshots of code are *not* helpful. You should paste the code into the question, and then use the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: Got it, sorry about that just copied and pasted it.

Comment: you want to set x_ticks https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your code as follows to obtain a bar chart

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel('Country')
ax.set_ylabel('Total Impressions')
ax.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

For additional options within the bar plotting tool, you may refer the documentation : https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html

Comment: when i try using this code i keep getting key value error 0 or it prints out even more empty charts

Comment: Can you paste the output you get when you print `x` or `y`.? Also when you print `type(x)`.?